# ASP.NET Postback User Not Logged in

Tags: asp.net, session, variables, textarea, save

OK I have a problem im not sure how to handle.

I have an asp.net vb website with MSSQL on the backend.  For every page, in the pre-init, it checks to see if the session("UserID") is logged in.  If its logged in, it loads, if not, it brings you to the login page.

One of my pages has a textarea that someone could spend 15 minutes writing in, after they are done, they hit save and it is suppossed to upload the data from the textarea to the database, which it does if they are logged in.

Where I am running into problems, is I will be uploading new webpages to the site which kicks all users off the site and forces them to relogin.

I know it would be a security flaw to let them write to the database without loggin in.

Is there a way I can do something different like save that textarea locally to their computer? Or some other way that I am not thinking of?

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is configure the session state to use Sql Server. In your web.config

```
<configuration>
  <sessionstate 
      mode="sqlserver" .....
```

This way the session will remain active when you upload new webpages which causes the web application to restart.

Answer (score 0):

Users are getting kicked off because when you deploy new pages, Host process restarts. and as you are using InProc sessions(assumption), sessions stored in memory are lost.

instead of storing sessions in memory you can store them in database. and whenever a user does a postback, check his session validity against database.

Answer (score 0):

You should post or notify your users when you are going to be making site changes, and do it at a time that you don't expect many users to be on your site (like 2am on a Sunday morning). (this may be obvious, maybe not - I'm not trying to sound like a jerk :D )

That being said, you could do ajax posts every few minutes that would allow partial saving of their work so that if you DO boot them all off, they would only have a few minutes of work lost.

You could also set up a secondary service that holds your database transactions until the main database is available to be written to. Essentially have your pages send their information to a server and write it to a temp database - have that system run chron jobs that check to see if your main DB is up, and then send all of its updates when its up again.

When you update the site it essentially kills all of their sessions - I have heard that there is something you can do to preserve sessions across updates like that, but I believe its MVC3 related.

Good Luck.